# Prove $B(a,\frac{1}{2}) \ge \frac{1}{a}$ for $a \ge 1$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

I would like to prove

$B(a,\frac{1}{2}) \geq \frac{1}{a}$ for $a \geq 1$,

where B represents the Beta function.

It seems to be true, but I haven't found a nice proof yet.
Tried to work with the integral formula but I couldn't get a clean picture.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this?

Here is a start with the Gamma function.

\begin{align*}
B(a,\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\Gamma(a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2})} \geq \frac{1}{a}
\end{align*}

Now I multiply both sides with $a$.

\begin{align*}
a \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2})} \geq 1
\end{align*}

Now I use the fact that $\Gamma(a+b) \leq \Gamma(a+c)$ for $b \leq c$.

\begin{align*}
a \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2})} \geq a \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(a+1)} = a \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a) \cdot \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{a \cdot \Gamma(a)} = \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) \geq 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Write it in terms of gamma functions, multiply through by $a$ and use the functional equation for gamma. It should be obviously true then.

Comment: I started based on your hint. What is the functional equation for gamma?

Comment: The most basic one: $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$. Then note the monotonicity of gamma for $a\ge 1$.

Comment: Okay, I used it by bounding $\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2}) \leq \Gamma(a+1)$ (see above). Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma(x)$ is increasing for $x\ge 3/2$.

Comment: What about $B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_0^1\frac{t^{a-1}}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt \geq\int_0^1t^{a-1}dt$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a\geq 1$, we have\begin{align*}
B\left(a,\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\int_0^1\frac{t^{a-1}}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt\\
&\geq\int_0^1t^{a-1}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{a}.
\end{align*}